# How to update authorization information in a KDC dynamically?

Tags: authorization, kerberos

I wish to add Kerberos authentication and authorization into a project that has a service server that interacts with a Hadoop cluster that has some users and permissions.

As far as I know, the KDC should be the one that checks for permissions and not the service server, but the thing is, if a user creates a new file on Hadoop I need to somehow update the permissions of the user over the new file.

How to inform the KDC that this user should now have access to that file?

Should I actually do that on the first place?